# Calling a function and having it call multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm having an issue in PyQt5 where if I some of my functions, it calls it however many times I've called it so far. I'll try to water down to relevant code.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, UI.MainUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    """The Main Window where everything happens"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Initializes  (Don't use partial as most of the variables
        aren't created yet)"""
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_buy_ship.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.game.current_player.buy_ship(self))

    def new_game(self):
        """Runs tha actual Game"""
        self.game = Game(self)
        self.game.play(self)

class Game(object):
    """The Game Class"""
    def __init__(self, window):
        """The Obvious"""
        self.window = window
        self.makeshitgo = True
        super(Game, self).__init__()

    def play(self, window):
        """starts the game"""
        while self.makeshitgo:
             for i in self.players:
                self.current_player = i
               if i.ship.name is None:
                    i.buy_ship(window)
                while self.myturn:
                    QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()
                    self.current_player.update_cargo(window)
                    time.sleep(.05)
             self.turn += 1

class Player:
    def __init__(self, ship, port, name):
        """Starts the player off with 0 everything and 5000 deblunes"""
        self.name = name

    def buy_ship(self, window):
        """Stops execution until ok/cancel is pressed"""
        window.change_ship("NA", "Galleon")

        def purchase():
            """buys the ship and updates money"""  # needs sell old ship
            if self.money >= int(window.V_Price.text()):
                self.ship = Ship(window.H_Ship_Name.text())
                self.change_money("down", self.ship.cost, window)
                window.textBrowser.append(self.ship.name)
                window.to_shipyard()
            else:
                window.textBrowser.append("You can't afford that brokearse")

        def cancel_purchase():
            """If you don't want to make a purchase"""
            if self.ship.name is None:
                window.textBrowser.append("You need a ship")
            else:
                window.to_shipyard()

        window.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(4)
        window.btn_buy.clicked.connect(purchase)
        window.btn_back_to_SY.clicked.connect(cancel_purchase)
```

Now every time I call i.buy_ship it calls it however many times I've called it so far(the first time it calls, the second time I push the button it calls twice, etc).  I feel as if it has to be in play() but I can't for the life of me find it.

*Edit* added buy_ship function in Player class

Comment: can we see the `buy_ship` function? I think it's more likely to be that instead.

Comment: It happens on more than the buy_ship function but sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you're binding a function to the buttons each time buy_ship is called. So the second time you call buy_ship. The previous binding is still there.

```
window.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(4)
window.btn_buy.clicked.connect(purchase)
window.btn_back_to_SY.clicked.connect(cancel_purchase)
```

Comment: Yeah this is the problem.  Either do the connection only once, or use the appropriate keyword to ensure single connections.

Comment: I'll try it, what do you mean "appropriate keyword"

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thank you internet via M4rtini and amicitas.

Comment: @amicitas What is this keyword? i could not find it in the docs.

Comment: I just window.btn_buy_ship.clicked.disconnect() when I call it and it seems to work.  I assume there is a better way but that was the first one I found that worked.

Comment: @Faller. Re: the keyword. It means e.g. `connect(purchase, QtCore.Qt.UniqueConnection)`. However, for this to work, the slot must be decorated with `QtCore.pyqtSlot` - and an error will be thrown when an attempt is made to make multiple connections. So it wouldn't be appropriate for your use-case.

Comment: Yup @Ekhumoro got it right.  I had forgotten that an error would be thrown.  The documentation on connection types is here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum.